# how to retrieve a field records by comparing the other fields mssql?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table; let it be called table1; with the following fields and data

```
msgid  msisdn teaserid send
1      333     1        1
2      333     1        0
3      444     2        1
4      444     2        1
5      444     3        1
```

I need a  query that returns those msgid for which send = 1 for every single records having same msisdn, teaserid. In the above case, i want msgid: 3,4,5 as result. 
How can this be done using mssql query?

Comment: I think your expected output is 3,4 and not 3,4,5 because in record#5, the msisdn and teaserid combination is different than the combination in record#4.

Comment: no, here 3,4 means same message splitted into two distinguish by same teaserid and both are send. and 5 is single message which is send. so i need 3,4 and 5 also.

Comment: @Ujjwal: What you want is to show the messages which are sent (as value equals 1) and with the same msisdn. The teaserid is just for messages that are splitted to several parts. You can use it to concatenate message but to show msgid only. You only need to use the fields send and msisdn.

Comment: @AristonAlcantara - I believe that if row with `id` 4 had a 0 for `send`, the OP would still want to send row with `id` 5. But 3 would no longer be sent. As such, both `msisdn` and `teaserid` matter.

Comment: @Ariston Alcantara: ya, Damien_The_Unbeliever  is right!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a cute use of the [window functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
declare @t table (msgid int,msisdn int,teaserid int,send int)
insert into @t (msgid,msisdn,teaserid,send) values
(1,333,1,1),
(2,333,1,0),
(3,444,2,1),
(4,444,2,1),
(5,444,3,1)

select * from (
select *,MIN(send) OVER (PARTITION BY msisdn,teaserid) as all1
from @t
)t
where all1 = 1
```

Result:

```
msgid       msisdn      teaserid    send        all1
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
3           444         2           1           1
4           444         2           1           1
5           444         3           1           1
```

By computing the `MIN(send)` across the `msisdn,teaserid` partitions, this can only be 1 if all of the `send` values are 1. If just one row has a 0, that will be the minimum for that partition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query to get the result

```
 select msgid 
 from table1 t 
 where send=1 
       and exists(select * from table
                  where send=1 
                  and msisdn=t.msisdn
                  and teaserid=t.teaserid and msgid != t.msgid)
```